# mov'ing stored value into DX results in Invalid Opcode from DOS

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, nasm

This is a rough, wip, hobby project I am doing, just to print simple 16-colour BMP's in dos. While tinkering with this I came across an unexpected error, that I have been unable to find information about.

The error in question disappears whenever the line moving **line_len into dx** is commented out, or when dx is substituted by ax.

```
new_line: 
    mov dx,[line_len]       ;;restock on pixels
    sub cx,[line_pad_len]   ;;decrement cx by the padlen -1 to skip the padding.
    add bx,[line_pad_len]   ;;increment read address.
    inc bx 
    loop process_loop       ;;return to loop and decrement.
```

The errors read (Although, the exact numbers change, as I assume is natural)

```
Invalid Opcode at EEAf 2D00 0217 0000 [... rest is zeroes ]
Invalid Opcode at 0013 0000 0202 0000 0013 0100 0002 0001 756E 6573 0864 0607 0405
Invalid Opcode at FECB 118A 0202 118A 189C 0000 4D4E 0000 [...]
```

and subsequently halts FreeDOS. When running debug on this, and stepping through, the last I can read is the (first) LOOP mnemonic, where normaly it would skip to the first change in the loop. (As far as I can tell.)

Unfortunately, I am a novice at both DOS and Assembly, and have been unable to find a solution with this info. If I replace DX with AX, the error goes away, but I'd rather try to understand why this error appears, so that I can avoid it in the future.

Entire source for the bmp->bin converter below.

```
org 100h

segment .code
    mov ax,3d00h            ;;OPEN FILE WITH 00 ACCESS. (READ ONLY)
    mov dx,filename
    int 21h
    jc exit                 ;;C FLAG MEANS ERROR.
    mov bx,ax               ;;GET FILE HANDLE

    mov ax,3f00h            ;;read file.
    mov cx,400h             ;;1024byte buffer available.
    mov dx,file_buffer      ;;address to the buffer.
    int 21h
    jc exit                 ;;C etc.
    mov cx,ax               ;;Move read bytes into cx.

    mov ax,3e00h            ;;close file
    int 21h
    jc exit

;;confirm_file:
    cmp word [file_buffer],4d42h
    jnz exit_bmp            ;;THIS IS NOT A BMP FILE.

    mov dx,00h
    mov ax, word [file_buffer+0022h]
    div word [file_buffer+0016h]
    dec ax
    mov [line_pad_len],ax

    mov dx, word [file_buffer+0012h]    ;;get width of image in pixels.
    cmp dx,0050h            ;;check if it's too wide for our screen.
;;jmp if it is.
    mov [line_len],dx
    mov bx, word [file_buffer+000ah]    ;;get offset of bmp array.
    mov cx, word [file_buffer+0022h]    ;;get size of pixel array + padding

process_loop:               ;;WE WANT 16 COLOUR BMP. 2PX/BYTE. LEFTMOST PX MOST SIGNIFICANT NIBBLE.
    mov al,[file_buffer+bx] ;;GET FIRST BYTE OF PIXEL ARRAY.
    inc bx                  ;;INCREMET OUR FILE READ LOCATION.
    dec dx
    jbe new_line            ;;if we are out of line, skip back.
    mov ah,al               ;;copy al into ah for safekeeping
    shr ah,04h              ;;ah shifted left 4bit. high nibble should be 0
    and al,0fh              ;;high nibble zeroed.
                            ;;WRITE NEW DATA TO BUFFER. (STILL UPSIDE DOWN)
    mov [outp_buffer+di],ah ;;write ax
    inc di
    mov [outp_buffer+di],al ;;write al
    inc di
    loop process_loop       ;;DECREMENT CX LOOP
    jmp write_file

new_line: 
    mov dx,[line_len]       ;;restock on pixels
    sub cx,[line_pad_len]   ;;decrement cx by the padlen -1 to skip the padding.
    add bx,[line_pad_len]   ;;increment read address.
    inc bx 
    loop process_loop       ;;return to loop and decrement.

write_file:                 ;;WARNING! THIS WILL DESTROY THE FILE IT WRITES TO.
    mov ah,3ch              ;;CREAT FILE
    mov dx,newfile          ;;PTR TO FILENAME
    mov cx,0000h            ;;FLAGS
    int 21h
    jc exit
    mov bx,ax               ;;file handle.

    mov ah,40h              ;;write to our file
    mov cx,di               ;;di should have bytes written.
    mov dx,outp_buffer      ;;get pointer to output buffer.
    int 21h
    jc exit                 ;;did we fail?

    mov ah,3eh              ;;Close our file.
    int 21h

exit:
    mov ah,4ch
    int 21h

exit_bmp:
    mov ax,4c66h
    int 21h

segment .data
filename:       db  "IN.BMP",00h
line_len:       dw  0000h
newfile:        db  "OUT.BIN",00h
line_pad_len:   dw  0000h
segment .bss
file_buffer:    resb    1024    ;;FIGURE OUT BETTER WAY TO DO LEN.
outp_buffer:    resb    1024    ;;FIGURE OUT BETTER STUFF.
```

Comment: What are the dimensions of your IN.BMP? I used a 16-color bitmap that is 128x96 pixels, and got an output file of 8190 bytes. There were no errors reported (I used DOSBox).

Comment: My IN.BMP is 80x32. I tested it again when I read this with a different size, and it did not fail. (Although the resulting bin is not correct, which is something else I need to look into, as it previously did, minus the padding from bmp and bottom-to-top order) But yes, a width of 80 seems to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've spotted a few problems in your code:

Don't use `JBE` after `DEC`. `JBE` jumps if `CF=1 or ZF=1`, but `DEC` doesn't modify the carry flag. The `CMP DX,50h` above *does* modify the carry flag however, so you could get an incorrect jump on the very first iteration depending on the value of `DX` (`line_len`). If you want to use `JBE` you should use `SUB DX,1` instead of `DEC DX`, because `SUB` modifies the carry flag.

---

Your updating of `CX` inside the loop is incorrect.
 Consider an image that is 80*32 pixels: The size of the pixel array will be 80*32/2 == 0x500 bytes. Your `line_len` will be 0x50, and your `line_pad_len` will be 0x500 / 0x20 - 1 == 0x27.
The `process_loop` runs 80 times for the first scanline, so `CX` will be 0x4B0 when you reach `new_line` for the first time. Then you decrease `CX` *again*; this time by 0x27+1. So in total your decreasing `CX` by 80+0x27+1 == 0x78 each scanline. Since 0x500 isn't evenly divisible by 0x78, `CX` will wrap around instead of reaching zero, thereby creating an infinite (or at least way too long) loop.

---

As mentioned above, your inner loop iterates `line_len` number of times per scanline (i.e. one iteration *per pixel*), and you're updating your file buffer index (`BX`) by 1 for every iteration. But the buffer only contains half as many bytes as there are pixels. You're also adding `line_pad_len` to `BX` at the end of each scanline, even though you've already incremented `BX` in your inner loop. The only thing that should be added to `BX` here is the number of *padding bytes*  (if any).